# Use Select-String for scraping web pages or some other method

Tags: powershell

I need to scrape a web page for some information and been trying to use Select-String to do it. I'm only interested in one portion of the page info among all the other content, currently testing this page to make sure its working correctly. This is the section that i'm interested in...

I've tried splitting the lines then using Select-String  - and have several other incarnations of close-but-not-close-enough examples found via the internet and here.

```
<div class="adrbox-light clearfix">
  <div class="adrbox-footer">
    <ul>
      <li>Name:
        <span class="darktext">John Test Value</span>
      </li>
      <li>Street Address:
        <span class="darktext">123 Sesame Street</span>
      </li>
      <li>City:
        <span class="darktext">AnyTown</span>
      </li>
      <li>State/Region:
        <span class="darktext">AnyStateRegion</span>
      </li>
      <li>Country:
        <span class="darktext">United States</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div id="adrbox-map" class="adrbox-map"></div>
</div>
```

the only lines I am interested in returning with Select-String is each line with the word "darktext" in them.

I've been trying to do it with Select-String but it never selects the lines and nothing is returned. How do I do this with Select-String or is there a better way to do it in Power Shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML is in an array (one line per array-item), try using `Where-Object` instead of `Select-String`:

```
$HTMLArray | Where-Object {$_ -match "darktext"}
```

Note that the right operand to `-match` is considered a regular expression and must be treated as such, so that if you wanted to match a string with a dot in it, e.g. `foo.bar`, you would have to escape the dot: `... $_ match "foo\.bar" ...`.

Comment: Its the object in "$web" returned from "$web = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.futurelivepagelinkhere.com/pages/adr-info).Content"

Comment: ```$web -split "`n" | Where-Object {$_ -match "darktext" }```

Comment: That's it Jeff! Works great. Thank You :)

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, you should click on the check mark next to it - this marks your question as answered, and also throws me a little bit of reputation on the site.